# Hibernate: Many To Many Relation with attributes: correct configuration with Annotations

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, cascade

I have a problem with Hibernate (Thanks to **Thomas** now the problem is more legible).

In Short:

**How to configure a ManyToMany association with Hibernate when the relationship has an attribute and we need save, delete and update in cascade?**

In Large:

Imagine the following DataBase:

```
             User     Profile
                M______N
                     |
                     attribute
```

There are 3 tables here:

```
"User", "Profile" and "User_Profile".
```

Now imagine User_Profile has 1 attribute for the relation (and obviously the keys).

Ok, now this is translating to Hibernate by the following:

```
 User:
 // The relation is Many to Many, but considering that it has an attribute, this is OneToMany with the ManyMany RelationShip
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", targetEntity=UserProfile.class)    
 @Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
 @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
 private Set<UserProfile> userProfile = new HashSet<UserProfile>();


 UserProfile:
 @Id    
 @ManyToOne(targetEntity=User.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)   
 @Cascade({CascadeType.LOCK})   
 @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="...", referencedColumnName="...") })  
 private User user; 

 @Id    
 @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Profile.class,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)    
 @Cascade({CascadeType.LOCK})   
 @JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="...", referencedColumnName="...") })  
 private Profile profile;
```

So, I think the configuration is correct, and the save, independently if the User has Profile childrens save all of them. The problem is when I try to **update** the user:

```
 getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().clear();
 getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate( user );
 getHibernateTemplate().getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().flush();
```

Hibernate don´t delete the Profile relation if there is an empty set of Profile childrens. Only add the profiles (override the old)... That´s rare... What´s the problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

All you actually do is remove the relation and thus theres no `DELETE` to cascade, that's why nothing gets deleted.

Try adding the Hibernate cascade type `DELETE_ORPHAN` (using the `@Cascade` annotation) to make Hibernate delete entities that are not referenced anymore.

Additionally, I'd not remove the `Mini` entities alone. If there's no relation, i.e. the set of `Mini`s is empty, it normally makes no sense to keep the `SuperMini` entities that now represent an empty collection (in rare cases it might make sense, just want you to think about whether you need them or not).

*Edit*:

Note that with `DELETE_ORPHAN` you should reuse the set, otherwise all the relations might be deleted and reinserted.

Basically Hibernate would then see the set being changed and would issue a delete for the "old" set and a reinsert for the "new" set. This could be wanted but in case you only want an update, i.e. only delete the entities that are not in the set anymore, you should do the following:

1. clear the set
2. add the "new" set to the reused and now cleared set using `addAll(...)`

This should trigger the update (and deletion of orphans) only.

Comment: First: thanks for your answer. If the object Super has a set of Mini and I update the collection in the Super entity with an empty set, I need that Hibernate launch the delete form the SuperMini Entity.

Comment: Note that Actually this is a M-N relation, not a 1M relation. All I need is to remove the relation between the Super Entity and the Mini Entity, not the Mini Entity.

Comment: @ganzux As I said, you need the `DELETE_ORPHAN` cascade type on the `superMini` relation in `Super`. There's one thing to keep in mind, though: you should reuse the set. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: So the SuperMini class, in the Super relation, I change the   _@Cascade({CascadeType.LOCK})_   to    _@Cascade({CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})_. Is it?

Comment: @ganzux You could also just _add_ `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` to the existing one.

Comment: @ganzux I just looked at your code again: you don't add that cascade type in `SuperMini` but in `Super` to the `superMini` property. I don't see any `CascadeType.LOCK` there, so I assume you put it to the wrong relation. You might also update your question to reflect the changes you made. - Btw, you don't actually have `private Super super;`, do you? This shouldn't even compile (`super` is a reserved keyword).

Comment: Super and Mini maybe are rare Entities... I will use Father and son instead.

Comment: Done @Thomas maybe now is more clear. THANKS A LOT for your help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6029/discussion-between-ganzux-and-thomas)